# Symfony calling functions between controllers

Tags: symfony, controller

Can anyone give me direction on how to accomplish cross controller variable exchange and/or function calls?

I'm new to Symfony and I have a reasonably complex practice sample site which has two controllers - PageController and BlogController.

PageController has actions to generate my home, about and contact page. The home page simply has a list of blogs.

The BlogController has all the CRUD related functions - create, delete etc

My issue is that I want to call my BlogController:createAction function from the PageController so I can present a blog create form above the blog listings on the homepage OR just pass the variable containing the new blog form data.

In addition, I need to find a solution which will allow the form to submit and the listings to refresh via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either using forward method directy

```
$response = $this->forward('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog:myFunction', array(
    'name'  => $name,
));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller

Or alternatively, you could define the blog controller as a service.

service.yml

```
services:
    your_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\BlogController
```

Then you can use

```
$service = $this->get('your_service');
$service->myFunction();
```

You could also look into setting up a form factory service (bit more advanced)

**UPDATE:**

Following your post I implemented the a service but got the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

This got fixed when I added the following line to the service declaration:

```
calls:
         - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although [@Tom Toms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736043/1173391) answer is correct, I would recommend another approach in order to minimize dependencies:

Just create a route for your Blog function and then use `$this->redirectToRoute` in your PageController thereby the action will be simply redirected to the assigned route, so you have no forwarding *(although I think that the forwad action will create nothing more then a redirect)* or service implementation with injections just a simple redirect