# Calling a function mixed by a part of its name and a variable

Tags: php

My variable `$column` returns `project`.

I would like to run the method `getProject()` dynamically.

This is what I have tried:

```php
$column = ucfirst($column);
$typeOfTask->get{$column}();
```

But i get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: App\Entity\TypeOfTask::$get

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `$typeOfTask->get($column);`

Comment: @Dilek that wouldn't work, since in your case `get` is the method and `$column` is the parameter.

Comment: is that symfony ? see this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734954/symfony-calling-functions-between-controllers

Comment: @Dilek yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that particular case you can simply use:

```php
$methodName = 'get' . ucfirst($column);
$typeOfTask->$methodName();
```

In this case if `$column == 'project'` then it will call method `getProject` on object `$typeOfTask`.